# css formatting not reflecting in html button

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a login page like instagram using html and css. But to format the button like instagram's login page, the css script is not working.

The button `<input type="submit" class="sub-btn">`
The CSS :

```
.wrapper .header .form .sub-btn{
    margin: 10px 0;
    background-color: #3897f0;
    border: 1px solid #3897f0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

But the formatting doesn't seem to reflect in the html page. Need help.

Comment: Are you wrapping your `.sub-btn` element in elements with the correct classes?

Comment: @NickParsons Sometimes I hate myself. I was refreshing the page but it showed no result. So I used Shift+f5 and it did. Sorry for such stupidity.

Comment: Ah, that will do it, I hate it when that happens haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
<Button class="sub-btn"></Button>
```

instead of

```
<input type="submit" class="sub-btn">
```

and be aware that is .wrapper .header .form .sub-btn address is correct or not

Answer (score 1):

Set display property as block or inline-block

```
display : block ;
```